# Simple Data manipulation task in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame like the following sample data.

```
qty_available<- c(13500, 8500, 4600)
supply_qty<- c(0, 1000, 0)
forecast<- c(1200, 400, 3000)
demand_q<- c( 100, 800, 6000)

df<- data.frame(qty_available, supply_qty, forecast, demand_q)
```

I am attempting to do the following manipulation: I want qty_available to equal previous qty_available + supply qty - forecast - demand quantity. I can ignore the first observation because it is irrelevant in the context of my task.

So in the second observation, we would have 13,500 + 1000 -400 -800 giving us 13,300. The third observation would then be the 13,300 + 0 - 3000 -6000 giving us 4300.

I have attempted this as follows, but it won't work as I don't think that the answers "flow through"

```
df<- mutate(df, qty_available = lag(qty_available) + supply_qty - forecast - demand_q)
```

I am trying to work this so that the answer ends up becoming 4300 for the third observation.

I am mimicking a process in Excel through R in which the correct value is 4300. I just can't figure out how to mimic that process in R.

How would I go about doing this in R? Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's fairly simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the third observation would give us -500, as the second qty_available observation is 8500 instead of 13,300.

So I think it would be 8,500 + 0 - 3000 - 6000 = -500.

If you fix the qty_available to the first qty_available (13,300), then we would expect the answer to be 4300.

The lag function takes the previous value in the rows instead of fixing it to the first value.

Comment: I think I may have phrased this poorly. The big question is, how would I go about coding this to make the answer be the 4300? That is the answer that I am looking for. I am essentially attempting to mimic a process that is done through excel in R in which 4300 is the answer.

Comment: Additionally, I would need the code to flow through a DF much larger than 3 observations.

Comment: Can you share the excel formula?

Comment: The excel data is in a completely different format, but in terms of this data assuming you exported it to excel in a CSV with headers, it would be the following for the second observation:  =A2+B3-C3-D3. Then just drag it down through the rest of the column